# the capslock functionaliy is reversed in Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, ubuntu-20.04, capslock

**Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** is running in **virtualbox**. The CapsLock is reversed when I turn it on.

Due to this when I have to type in **lowercase** I have to turn keyboard's CapsLock **ON** and when I have to type in **uppercase** have to turn **OFF** the CapsLock.

How to fix this CapsLock issue?

Answer (score 3):

This can sometimes happen on certain OSes in Virtualbox when you save the machine state with capslock set to ON.

You should be able to fix it by setting capslock to ON on your keyboard, saving the machine state, switching capslock OFF on your keyboard and then restarting the VM.

Comment: saving the state of VM and restarting it will take lot of time my system is very old and slow. It will take lot of time of do the steps which is mentioned and there is also a change that even after restarting the VM the capslock reversing problem might occur isn't it?

Comment: There's always a chance of that, but I don't see any other answers or solutions here, and this is most likely to fix it, so I'd suggest trying it. Think about what is more inconvenient - having to deal with an inverted capslock button, or just taking some time to restart it, solve the issue and forget about it. It's not going to magically fix itself.

Answer (score 1):

This can be more complicated. I've seen your situation occasionally and it is frustrating. I never figured out how I got into it or really how I got out of it.

This happened again today on VB 6.1.38 running on OS X 12.6.  This time my guest Ubuntu 18.04 was configured with gnome-tweaks using CapsLock to choose an alternate keyboard (CapsLock off = US Keyboard; CapsLock on = Dvorak). The characters were shifted opposite of the CapsLock, but the keyboard choice followed CapsLock correctly.

The result of pressing the US Keyboard "g" key (= Dvorak "i" key):

- "G" CapsLock off, no shift
- "g" CapsLock off,    shift
- "I" CapsLock  on, no shift
- "i" CapsLock  on,    shift

Whatever code was choosing the keyboard layout was seeing CapsLock as it actually was, while whatever code was choosing between upper and lower case letters was seeing an inverted CapsLock.

Having CapsLock enabled during a save or a start up, didn't solve my "G vs g" problem (but it did alter whether the primary or alternate keyboard was chosen by CapsLock (swapping "G" for "I")).   Holding down Left or Right Shift at save or start seemed to only affect maybe the first key press.

I finally cleared things up by turning on the on-screen keyboard in the Guest (Ubuntu's Universal Access preferences), but I'm not quite sure how. Possibly it was fixed by the on-screen keyboard starting up.  (To confirm the fix stuck, I turned off the on-screen keyboard and saved the VM.  When it restarted, the keys worked as desired.)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1146659)